# How to find who last modified the table in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the user who last modified particular table in SQL Server. 
`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` provides information about last modified date for the table but I am looking for last modified by. Is there a way to figure out which login last modified specific table?

Comment: Was the table modified directly or through a stored procedure by the user?

Comment: I am trying to create a insert, update and delete trigger on the table so that if anybody tries to perform DML action, it should insert information like modified_date, modified_by, row_id etc in a log table.

Comment: In that case, I think you could just do something like this as this article suggests: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone for looking into my question and providing suggestions. I used below script in my trigger to get the last_modified_by.

```
   DECLARE @login_name NVARCHAR(200)
   SELECT  @login_name = loginame
   FROM  sys.sysprocesses
   WHERE   spid = @@SPID
```

Comment: This doesn't give the last user that modified a specific table, it gives the name of the user that runs the query

Answer (score 3):

Try this out and see if it helps:

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255) 
SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc'  
FROM sys.traces   
WHERE is_default = 1;  

SELECT gt.HostName, 
       gt.ApplicationName, 
       gt.NTUserName, 
       gt.NTDomainName, 
       gt.LoginName, 
       gt.SPID, 
       gt.EventClass, 
       te.Name AS EventName,
       gt.EventSubClass,      
       gt.TEXTData, 
       gt.StartTime, 
       gt.EndTime, 
       gt.ObjectName, 
       gt.DatabaseName, 
       gt.FileName, 
       gt.IsSystem
FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filename, DEFAULT) gt 
JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 
WHERE EventClass in (164) 
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Comment: You are using the default trace which does not include who modified a row in a table.

Comment: According to this article here, default trace file logs in all objects altered event (which I would think would include modifying a row in a table). https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/

Comment: I believe that means who altered a structure (alter table...) not who added a row. Why don't you try it and tell us what you find.

Comment: @benjamin moskovits I tried this before I posted and saw all recent events on a table that had been created last month.  I was wondering if it would work the same way for Rose.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to enable the built in auditing in SQL Server, which isn't enabled by default, or, write your own method of auditing what happens.

If this is for something that has already happened, then I think you might be out of luck.